# Proving this polynomial is in $ K[X]$

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

This appears in a bigger context, but in summary, I have $K\subset L$ extension of finite fields and $\alpha\in L$ such that $L=K(\alpha)$. Also, $G=Aut_K L$. Now, I need to prove the following:

$$f_K^{\alpha}= \prod_{\sigma\in G}  (X-\sigma(\alpha)) $$

But I think that’s pretty easy once you prove $g=  \prod_{\sigma\in G}  (X-\sigma(\alpha))\in K[X] $. How should I do it?

Comment: Not true in general: $K=\mathbb Q, L=\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)$. Perhaps you mean $L/K$ Galois?

Comment: You used the tag [tag:finite-fields]. Do we know that $K$ is finite? It plays a role, because the objection raised by lhf becomes moot, if $K$ and $L$ are finite. Anyway, you should not rely on the choice of tags alone to convey such facts.

Comment: Yes, sorry. $K$ is finite and $L$ is a finite extension. I’m editing the question.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the clarification. A solution needs to explain, why the assumption $L=K(\alpha)$ is necessary? In other words, what goes "wrong" (or at least "differently"), if $K(\alpha)$ is a proper subfield of $L$? Otherwise $g$ won't be irreducible over $K$.

Comment: Yeah, I think that is what it means. But I do not know what the corresponding statement would be.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, denote by $f$ the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$.
Note that your statement is equivalent to that the set of all roots of $f$ is exactly the set $\{\sigma(\alpha):\sigma\in\text{Aut}_K(L)\}$.

First, for any $\sigma\in\text{Aut}_K(L)$,
we have $f(\sigma(\alpha))=\sigma(f(\alpha))=0$ because $\sigma$ fixes $K$.
Conversely,
let $\beta$ be a root of $f$ in an algebraic closure of $K$ containing $L$.
Since $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are conjugates,
there is an isomorphism $\varphi:L=K(\alpha)\to K(\beta)$ fixing $K$.
This shows that $K(\beta)\cong L$.
Now, since [any extension between finite fields is a normal extension](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/790759/806703),
the fact that $\alpha\in L$ implies that $\beta\in L$,
so we have $K(\beta)\le L$.
Since $K(\beta)$ and $L$ are both finite-dimensional vector spaces,
we then have $K(\beta)=L$.
We have now shown that $\varphi$ is in fact an automorphism of $L$ fixing $K$, and $\varphi(\alpha)=\beta$, as desired.

Comment: Actually, since $K\subset L$ is always a Galois extension and $g$ is fixed by all automorphisms in $\text{Gal}(K/L)$, we can, by comparing coefficients, conclude that the coefficients of $g$ are fixed by those automorphisms as well. Then the coefficients of $g$ must lie in $K$ because they lie in the fixed field for the whole group $\text{Gal}(K/L)$.